# TypeScript: Declaration of variables / attributes in classes / methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can somebody give me answer to the following two questions:

1) Why isn't it possible to declare variables in methods like an attribute in the comprehensive class?

What I want: `private foo: string` (compiler error)
What I have to do: `var foo: string` (no compiler error)

2) When do I declare a variable as an attribute of the class and when do I declare a variable only in the method? I'm not sure if the Java knowledge fits in this case. Spontaniously I would say it depends on the scope of the variable (if it is needed f.e. in two or more methods -> attribute of class OR otherwise -> variable of a method).

Thank you!

Comment: Because variable created inside method have only one possible scope - method scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering you would be easier if you mentioned [what you're trying to do](http://xyproblem.info/).

TypeScript private class members aren't actually private at runtime; if you want actual privacy, you should use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) like so:

```
class Foo {
  getSomethingPrivate: () => number
  constructor() {
    var somethingPrivate = 1;
    this.getSomethingPrivate = function() {
      return somethingPrivate;
    }
  }
}
```